# how to bind list to gridview in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a demo web internet mvc4 with web api,now I get the stub that I can not bind the list to gridview or table to show item,here is my code.

My controller,

here is the json web api return:

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"test2","Category":"test","price":23.0},
{"Id":2,"Name":"test1","Category":"test","price":12.0}]
```

here is the controller,

```
public ActionResult Index()
 {
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:54854");

  // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
  HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Values").Result;
  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
   var products = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Products>>().Result;
    return View(products);
  }
  else
  {
   return View();
  }
```

Modal

```
public class Products
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Category { get; set; }
        public Double price { get; set; }
    }
```

View Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
```

would you please continue to show product list to gridview ? thankyou very much

Comment: where you have bind the gridview ??? you have just throw the result to view. but you have not bind the data any where in view please look at the link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576514/AplusBeginner-27splusTutorialplusonplusVariousplus

Comment: Dear raman,I have not know how to bind the list product to gridview,so I would like to ask any one can continue work this step for me.thanks your answer

Comment: T bui, do you want to hire a developer to do this task for you??

Comment: in any ways,I do now know how to show that list to gridview in asp.net mvc4.I would like to ask any solution to show list product to gridview,thanks